# Organising HTML background images

Tags: html, css

So I have two Images as a background and I cant figure out how to separate them and put a black strip in-between them. Ideally it would be big enough to fit a paragraph in and the top/bottom sides faded in with images above and below. W3schools only helps so much and I'm not having any luck finding answers.
Any help would be apreciated.   :)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Ait website</title>
<style>
   body {
     background: url("Images/BannerA.jpg"), url("Images/BannerB.jpg");
     background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
   }
</style>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Google exists for a reason. In short your need to set `background-position` in your CSS - https://css-tricks.com/css-basics-using-multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is to create 2 different `divs` with different backgrounds.
Once it's done, You can style it however you want, eg. giving each div 50% width and so on

Answer (score 0):

without creating two divs it would be difficult for you to put both images as background . And give width 50% to both and don't forget to set display as inline-block.